# jacoco code coverage to skip ui code

Tags: android, code-coverage, jacoco

I execute Jacoco unit test code coverage and it shows up all the code that need to covered in unit testing.

How to I avoid the test coverage from showing ui code, like the code in onCreate(), onAttach()(for fragment).
I don't want the code coverage for the views but jacoco gives that as well. 
Is there a way I can eliminate it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how you run jacoco, but I'm assuming that you use the [jacoco maven plugin](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html). There you can always [exclude](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html#excludes) files and directories.